# android - make call on overflow menu button click

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a menu item in my overflow menu named "panic", it should make a call on an android device once clicked. I am using eclipse.

This is the menu xml of the screen.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.municipality.HomeActivity" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

    <item 
         android:id="@+id/action_panic"
         android:title="Panic"/>

</menu>
```

This is the onOptionsItemSelected code that i got from an answer here on "stackoverflow.com":

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        case R.id.action_panic:
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));
            startActivity(callIntent);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

And finally this is a bit of the androidManifest file:

```
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>


    <application
```

When i run the app on the emulator the overflow menu shows the panic button but i get no action when clicked.

Comment: Does a `System.out.println("Button press detected!")` show you made it to the Intent?

Comment: `ACTION_CALL` may not work on an emulator -- I have never tried it. Try your code on an actual device.

Comment: can you paste the more code like "onCreateOptionsMenu" and onOptionsItemSelected method